# Проблема с загрузкой картинки на imgur по API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Может кто-то подскажет в чем проблема?

Код:

```
function readURL(index) {
jQuery("#img-file-input-" + index).click();
jQuery("#img-file-input-" + index).change(function () {
    input = this;
    var input;

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                headers: {
                    'authorization': 'Client-ID my_ID'
                },
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'image': e.target.result,
                    'type': 'base64'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    jQuery("#img-upload-"+index).attr('src', response.data.link);
                }, error: function() {
                    alert("Error while uploading...");
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
});
}
```

Ошибка: `POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image 400 (Bad Request)`